# NAT Virtual Host setting in router not working

Tags: router, virtualhost, nat, dynamic-dns

been working on this for past 1 week now, no break.

So I have this local network with IP range 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.255

I have a apache server running on 192.168.1.90 on port 80

So I set up a NAT Virtual host in my router. Router setting

Then I restarted the router (NOTE: the settings remained unaltered after restart) and then tried to access by typing in my external IP 122.174.*.170 which I took from whatismyip.com

but the router itself is responding to the call, and the request is not getting routed to the server on my LAN.

Router responds

So what have I done wrong, and how can i fix it, totally confuses me.

Comment: Are you on the network when you try to use the external IP address?

Comment: yes i am in the same local network as the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response to a request sent from a machine on the network to the DNATed public IP (122.174.*.170) of a server on the network is dropped, because it comes back addressed from the internal address (192.168.1.90), an address that the machine did not make a request to.  Some routers have a setting that would allow you to send all such traffic through the router to avoid this problem. A cheap router would probably not do it.

A work-around:

- Setup separate DNS servers - one external, and one internal. The internal dns would point your domain name to 192.168.1.90.  You can also just modify the host file on each internal machine.